# how can i run this function i want to provide data in the input then pass it into function so do i do it properly?

Tags: javascript

how can i run this function i want to  provide data in the input then pass it into function so do i do it properly?

```
var Statistics = {
   "2030": {
      "name": "abdulrhmanhamdi",
      "class": "frist Year",
      "friends": [ "mahmoud", "ahmad" ]
   },
   "4050": {
      "name": "mahmoud",
      "class": "sec year",
      "friends": [ "abdulrhmanhamdi", "ahmad" ]
   },
   "9080": {
      name: "ahmed",
      class: "third year",
      "friends": []
   },
};

function updateStatistics(id, prop, value) {

   if (value === "") {
      delete Statistics[id][prop];
   } else if (prop === "friends") {
      Statistics[id][prop] = Statistics[id][prop] || [];
      Statistics[id][prop].push(value);
   } else {
      Statistics[id][prop] = value;
   }
   return Statistics;
}

var buttun = document.getElementById = "10b";
var idx = document.getElementById('input1');
var classx = document.getElementById('input2');
var valuex = document.getElementById('input3');

buttun.addEventListener('click', function() {
    //enter code here
   console.log(
      updateStatistics(idx.value, classx.value.tostring, valuex.value.toString)
   );
});
```

Comment: im sorry im aware of the code mistake in the  console part

Comment: No need to use `toString`, it's already a string.

Comment: What is your expected outcome? Can you give a few examples of what values you would give to the `updateStatistics` function and what you results you expect from the function return?

Comment: @abdulrhmanhamdi Was the answer below any help to you?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:

I would start with changing your Statistics object to an array. Arrays are a better data structure to handle when you need to manipulate data, in my opinion. I will show you why.

Here is how I would structure your data:

```
var Statistics = [
   {
      id: "2030",
      name: "abdulrhmanhamdi",
      class: "frist Year",
      friends: [ "mahmoud", "ahmad" ]
   },
   {  id: '4050',
      name: "mahmoud",
      class: "sec year",
      friends: [ "abdulrhmanhamdi", "ahmad" ]
   },
   {
      id: '9080',
      name: "ahmed",
      class: "third year",
      friends: []
   },
]
```

It is not recommended to mutate to much-existing data that you are working on. Instead, I would recommend cloning the Statistics array by using [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a new modified version.

I would skip deleting keys form your object as it is time-consuming, just keep the same structure and allow them to have an empty string.

```
function updateStatistics(id, key, inputValue, values) {   
  return values.map(value => {
    const {friends = [], ...rest} = value

    if (value.id === id) {

      return {
        ...value,
        [key]: key === "friends" ? [...friends, inputValue] : inputValue
       }

      }

      return value
    })
}
```

### **So what is happening in this function?**

Inside the map function, it starts by [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the value for each object in the array. By doing `friends = []` I can make sure that the variable `friends` always default an array in case it does not exist.

After that, we can return an object. By starting the object with `...value` we can clone the object we are currently working on. This is called a [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Next, we change the value for whatever key has been passed to the function via the form submit. If the key is "friends" we will copy the current "friends" array using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and then add a new value after.  If the key is anything else then we pass the whatever the value is as a string. Instead of deleting the key I would just keep an empty string. You can always validate it to false when empty if needed.

---

Next, for your inputs, wrap them in a form and listen for a submit of that form to get your data:

```
var form = document.querySelector("#myForm");

form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {  
  event.preventDefault();
  const { id, key, value} = event.target

  Statistics = updateStatistics(id.value, key.value, value.value, Statistics)

});
```

And here a simple HTML version of the form:

```html
<form id="myForm"/>
  <input id="id"/>
  <input id="key"/>
  <input id="value"/>

  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```